# $watch works but not $watchCollection

Tags: angularjs

This works:

```
$scope.$watch('cities', function(){
   alert("fire");
}, true);
```

This dosen't work:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[cities]', function(){
  alert("fire")
}, true);
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

$scope.cities is hooked up to some checkboxes.

Comment: If the `$scope.cities` is an array (or object) collection then it should be `$scope.$watchCollection('cities', function() {` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `$watchCollection` states that it *shallow* watches the `object` passed to it and fires whenever the object changes. So in case of arrays, it fires when any of the elements changes, but **not** when some *deep* property inside the element changes.  Also, it doesn't take a third argument (as `$watch` does for `objectEquality`). In your case, the object `cities` probably never changes in reference.

However, if you had:

```
  $scope.cityList = [cities];

  $scope.$watchCollection('cityList', function () { alert('fire'); });

  // As a response to some event:
  $scope.cityList[0] = newCities;
```

then the watcher should fire.